# Gradle create multiple task types in one task

Tags: gradle

Is there a way to create multiple tasks in one gradle task as shown below,

```
task zipFiles() {
   doLast {
      copy{
          from( "../licenses" ) {
              include '**/*.txt'
          }
          into "../$releaseFolder/licenses"
      }
      zip {
          from("../$releaseFolder/licenses")
          include '*'
          into "licenses"
          destinationDir = file("../$releaseFolder/")
          archiveName = "licenses.zip"
      }
   }
}
```

OR i need to create multiple tasks for copy and zip , ( this created large set of tasks in build file ).

Comment: The [distribution plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `zip` method in Gradle. You can either use a task of type `Zip` (preferred), or use the Ant `zip` task. Also, you wouldn't typically go through a staging directory, but put contents into the zip right from their original locations. If necessary, you would declare another task that creates an exploded zip (and shares much of the `Zip` task's definition).